# VBA writing values on chart (bars)

Tags: vba, excel, charts

This is the code I'm using to

```
Dim ejex As String, ejey As String
Dim graficos As String
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

ejex = "C" + CStr(cont) + ":" + "C" + CStr(conta)
ejey = "K" + CStr(cont) + ":" + "N" + CStr(conta)

graficos = ejex & "," & ejey

Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(graficos)
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart

cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
```

[image]

This is the expected graph 
[image]

Is there anyway to plot those values on every bar on this graph? I'm actually doing it adding textbox with excel on graph and I want to add them through the macros, since the graph is automated and might change every time the macros is active.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add *Data Labels* to each plotted series:

```
...
cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng

Dim ser As Series
For Each ser In cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection
    ser.ApplyDataLabels
Next
```